# installation on btrfs - "/" shows as "/home" after install

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, btrfs

I am playing a little with installing ubuntu server on btrfs (in a VM for playing purposes yet)

I make 2 partitions at installation time

`/boot`   (ext4) and
`/`    (btrfs)

after the installation is complete a lsblk (as well as mount) shows
`/boot` (ext4)
`/home`  (btrfs)
though on my `/dev/sda` drive.

Can anyone draw sense from that?

Comment: there is an fstab entry for '/' (with option subvol=@) AND and entry for '/home' (subvol=@home). Seems that has been created at installation. I was expecting that I'd create subvolumes (if I wanted to) manually AFTER installation. Maybe that was a false assumption OR I still could do so, if I wanted to

Comment: no, iirc, the installer, with a btrfs root, creates a subvolume for home by default

Comment: so, how do I come to a scenario where it actually does what I want? 250MB '/boot' & a 31GB '/'    (with a '/home' inside of that)? I mean at the moment I don't even really understand, nor see where my '/' actually is

Comment: maybe the standard method using the ubuntu installer is not the way to go with btrfs? Could you make a btrfs partition with the subvolumes you want first and then just point the installer to those in a second step?